# Where remote docker-compose do it's job - remote or locally

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When using `DOCKER_HOST="ssh://user@host" docker-compose up` will docker create/prepare all images locally and then send to remote or all work will be done on remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything is done on the remote system.  The two specific things that are local:

- The `docker-compose.yml` file itself is local.
- If you `build:` an image, the context directory is local.  (But the build itself is done on the remote Docker daemon; the build context is sent across the network, which could be slow if it's a large directory.)

Otherwise everything is remote.  Notably:

- `volumes:` that reference host directories reference directories on the *remote* system.
- If you specify `network_mode: host`, it uses the *remote* host's host network.
- If you specify `ports:`, you can access the service through the *remote* host's IP address or DNS name.
- Docker objects like networks and volumes live exclusively on the remote system.